# finding the maximum increase in an random array

Tags: algorithm

Suppose that I have an array of random reals, how do I the indices pair `(i, j)` where `j<i` and

`maximise (a[j] - a[i])` in `O(n ln(n))` time

n ln n sugguest recursions. So I was thinking of sorting the array in n ln n sort. but then the min and mix of the sorted array might not satisfy `j<i`

The difference `a[j]-a[i]` depends on all i , j so scanning all the possible permutation is `O(n^2)`. Does anybody have a suggestion on how I can divide the problem space?

Comment: The `ln(n)` really suggests divide-and-conquer (your recursion); the factor of `n` suggests that you need to do it once for every element in the array.

Comment: Please add some examples for better understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find `max(a[j] - a[i])` among all pairs `(i, j)` where `j < i`.

You can do it in O(n) without much problem.

For each index `i`, to maximize `a[j] - a[i]` expression we need to find `max(a[j])` on interval `[0 .. i - 1]`. So, let's move from left to right (increase `i`) and keep current maximum value of `a[j]`.

```
int maxa = a[0];
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    int current = maxa - a[i];
    if (current > best) {
        best = current;
    }
    maxa = max(maxa, a[i]);
}
```

Comment: I want to find the indices pair

Comment: Thats not a problem, just keep track of which js trigger an update to best, and which is trigger an update to maxa.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array, but keep track of the original position of each element. Then scan through the array starting from both ends and working your way toward the middle until you find a pair that was originally in the correct order.

Comment: Not sure I understand yet.  Suppose after sorting, you compare the first and last elements and find that the first's original index is larger than the last's.  Which 2 elements do you compare next?  Second and last?  First and second-to-last?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand Nikitas solution. I don't see a 'j' but an 'n'. Is the outer loop missing?

For an array of 10 values, it would make 9 differences, then 8, 7, 6, ... to 1; right?

My solution would be:

```
int a[] = {9, 3, 5, 2, 7, 4, 6, 8, 0, 1};
// find starting point (3)
int start = 0;
for (; start < a.length -1 && a[start] > a[start+1];)
    ++start;
// find upper bound (8)
int upper = start; 
for (int j = start + 1; j < a.length; ++j)  
{
    if (a[j] > a[upper])
        upper = j;
}
// find lower bound (2)
int lower = start;
for (int l = lower; l < upper; ++l)
{
    if (a[l] < a[lower])
        lower = l;
}
System.out.println ("from:\t" + a[lower] + " to: " + a[upper]);
```

In prosa: You search a starting point, which isn't 9 in the example, because there is no bigger value to the right, but 3 is.

From 3 you search the maximum to the right, which is 8.

Between 3 and 8 the smallest value lower than 3 is 2. There you got the maximum interval.